# Why is there background usage in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I was testing the REST API via HTTP yesterday and you can see that on the graph. Overnight, however, my database has been using bandwidth (2.65kb-3.58kb/hour) in the background. Why is this happing? Is there any way to stop this? 
[image: Firebase usage]

EDIT: Added rules

```
{
"rules": {
    ".indexOn": ["abc","def","ghi"],
  ".write": "auth.uid === '<uid>'",
  ".read": "auth.uid === '<uid>'"
  } 
}
```

Comment: What security rules are set up on the database? 3k is nothing. This is such a tiny amount than any number of HTTP requests (random web crawlers, accessing your admin console, et al) can account for that tiny amount of overhead.

Comment: Hmm... I think I set my PC to sleep, but when I woke up it was on (just the screen was off). I wonder if it was the console checking for updates every few seconds. I don't see how my rules would account for anything, as all I did was set read/write permissions to a uid.

Comment: Your rules would tell us if the data is read/write world. Which would help us narrow the possible sources.